# Custom view from module not showing in android studio palette

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created android studio module that is supposed to be a android ui framework. Framework has few components like custom buttons, custom layouts etc. and if I include it into app i can see them in palette under "Project"

[image: Imgur]

Next steps in development is to enable user to import framework using gradle and I managed to to that using jfrog but when you import into your project you are not able to see components in palette.

I tried importing just .jar and .aar files but nothing happened. And if you write xml manually components are shown in preview window normally

here is [git](https://github.com/wleorule/CMYK-UI) and [jfrog](https://bintray.com/cmykui/maven/cmykui/)

P.S.: keep in mind that project is still in development so git documentations is not full!

Thanks in advance, Leo

EDIT: 
If you open new project you can import framework using gradle. 
Just add:

```
maven {
        url  "https://cmykui.bintray.com/maven"
}
```

to your root build.gradle file and

```
implementation 'hr.foi.air2018.cmykui:cmykui:0.3.6'
```

to your app build.gradle

if you want to try out a component you can add

```
<hr.foi.air.cmykui.component.ButtonComponent
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

to see if framework is imported.

Comment: I've tried and seems to work normally. Git download, import module (cmykui), add dependencies and build then components shows up. So, may be failed while packing, I think.

Comment: thanks for you comment, maybe I didn't explain good enough. So there is no components in palette if you import framework using gradel (maven)  or try to import jar. So if you create new project and add `maven {
            url  "https://cmykui.bintray.com/maven"
        }` to your root gradle and `implementation 'hr.foi.air2018.cmykui:cmykui:0.3.6'`  to your app gradle you will be able to use framework but component won't show in palette.

Comment: Ya. I'm testing aar now. It doesn't show up...

Comment: yeah, so I tried adding `if(!isInEditMode()) {
            init(context);
        }` to component and extending it just from view it didn't help ether.

Comment: It's a resource import problem normally, so codes doesn't affect, I tnink.

Comment: so you are saying that problem is in android studio?

Comment: Yes. It's an android studio problem, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an Android Studio problem. It doesn't show View subclasses in imported modules to the Project tab of Design panel of XML.

Reason 1.

Android Studio doesn't show View subclasses in dependencies to the Project tab of Design panel.

For example, even if `implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'` exists in module(app) build.gradle, `android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout` doesn't show up in the Project tab of design panel. As auto-complete prompts it in Text tab of the xml, indexer can find them. So, Android Stuidio should check them if it is a public View class or not and add to Project tab, but it doesn't.

Reason 2.

I also tried with a quite simple module which contains a View subclass. It is shown in development stage (having source codes in that module), but if once built and imported as aar, it isn't.

I've tried with this.

```
public class CustomView extends View
{
    public CustomView(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

I also checked with `cmykui` module in the question, but the result is same. If imported from Git with source code, it appears. If imported as aar , it doesn't.